# angular JS http post data sending

Tags: angularjs, post

I have 6 forms and among those following form alone is not submitting params.

```
$scope.submit_s = function(isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
        console.log($scope.school_); //value is printing here
        $http.post(form_submit_url, $scope.school_).then(function(result) //here it is not sending params
            {
                var status = result.data.status.status;
                if (status == "success") {
                    // $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('jobData');
                }
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?  It is unclear in what way the above code fails.  What params? Is it not sending on the post or on the .then block?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: please provide console error or status code which you getting while posting data.

Comment: @DavidL in above code after console.log is the post request. Where as $scope.school_ is the parameters i want to send. It does print in console but doesn't send in the request header. form_submit_url is "/url.php".

Comment: @sumitchauhan there is no problem in response problem. 
When i call url using http in angular $scope.school_ is not sending any parameters.